# How to retain the output of the first job in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a shell script in my git which downloads huge android workspace (takes 90 minutes) & performs some operations & refines it & then I trigger some checks on another tool(via same shell script).

So until now I have configured the jenkins where it checkouts the shell script & runs it.
This shell script takes 90 minutes to download such a huge repo IN TO THE SAME WORKSPACE & then triggers some check on other tool(via its api).

But problem is if i just do minor improvements to the shell script & re run the job the entire workspace with previously refined sources gets wiped out & again I have to wait 90 minutes to perform this check.

Is there any way to optimize it so that i can retain the previously refined sources & only update the shell script in the workspace

I am looking to automating in jenkins But being a novice I am stuck how to do it.
Any help would be helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to download all the stuff to different folder, run 'chown' on the folder to make user 'jenkins' owner of the repo. Set your script to check the folder.

For the test purpose it will work.